# Radio buttons wont align to the left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a modal and everything has come along perfectly except my radio buttons. No matter what I try I don't understand how to move them to the left like the other elements in my form. All I want to do is move the radio buttons to the left and align them with the other elements like normal radio buttons.

```css
.feedback-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.feedback-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-background">

  <div class="feedback-content">

    <img src="E:\IIT\Lectures\WEB\coursework1\Images\feedbackimg1.jpg" alt="Givefeedback" style="width:100px;height:100px;">

    <form action="">

      Name:
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name"> E-Mail:
      <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail"> What do you think about us?<br>
      <textarea rows="6" cols="33" name="comment "></textarea>
      <br> How would you rate us ?
      <br>

      <label>
        <input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Excellent ">Excellent
        <input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Very Good ">Very Good
        <input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Average ">Average
        <input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Poor ">Poor
        <input type ="radio " name="rating " id="rating " value="Extreamly Poor ">Extreamly Poor
      </label>
      <br>
      <br>

      <a href="# " id="btn1 ">SUBMIT</a>

    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dcag0167/2/

Comment: You want them to be align verticaly or horizontal?

Comment: vertically good sir , like how the normal radio buttons would be , see now its in the middle and the text fields above and the buttons arent aligned properly i want them to be aligned so it looks proper . I hope i am clear enough

Comment: Can the HTML be changed?

Comment: @ajstyles your immediate problem is that `width: 50%` applied to `input` (just restrict it to `input[type=text]` in your CSS and do not apply `display: inline`) but there are MANY more problems in your HTML: unclosed tags, extra quotes, duplicated IDs (and probably some more I didn't even see)

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO as long as it works, yes sir

Comment: Are the inputs supposed to be inside the `<label>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a lot of work an little bugs in your code. I will focus on the radio buttons. 2 main errors.

1- You are setting the radio buttons width to 50% with:

```
input {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Solution comes to reset it in its own style

```
input[type="radio"]{
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

2- You are making all your text and radio buttons to just one `label` tag. This is not a good pratice. We can set on label for each radio button and text. An by adding its display to block, they will align.

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this helps :>

```css
.feedback-background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.feedback-content{
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
}

input {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

label {
    display: block;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    width: auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-background">
    <div class="feedback-content">
        <img src="E:\IIT\Lectures\WEB\coursework1\Images\feedbackimg1.jpg" alt="Givefeedback" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
        
        <form action="">
            Name:
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
            E-Mail:
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
            What do you think about us?<br>
            <textarea rows="6" cols="33" "name="comment"></textarea>
            <br>
            How would you rate us?
            <br>
            
            <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Excellent">Excellent</label>
            <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Very Good">Very Good</label>
            <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Average">Average</label>
            <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Poor">Poor</label>
            <label><input type ="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="Extreamly Poor">Extremely Poor</label>
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <a href="#" id="btn1">SUBMIT</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you , It worked like magic , i was aware of the fact that it was due to one of those other feedback class css but couldn't pinpoint on what it was and width was least on my mind.Thank you for all the help. But if it is not much to ask may i know what issues and bugs i have on my html so i can do better next time. I am still relatively very new so anything i get to learn is gold.Thank you so much

Comment: [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) will help you at finding this things. A lot is common practice and some standars. One personal opinion is to never leave words fying in your markup. Allway surrond them by at least a ``<p>``

Comment: Duly noted . Thank you so much for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: Mr BLANCO i did follow your directions and it did wonders how ever a small issue came up afterwards the image alignment in IE and Chrome changed. I made a question regarding it . If it isn't too much to ask could u take a look at it . Sorry for bothering during your busy schedule I'm assuming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205236/image-alignment-changed-in-ie-edge-and-google-chrome?noredirect=1#comment89393212_51205236

Comment: I just logged in and it looks you already got an answer. If you ever need any help, you can contact me via email: blancogerardo94@gmail.com.  Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the entire `input` css styles and just keep one style.

Next, I changed your `HTML` to include a `<label>` for each radio button. That way, you can also click the `<label>` to have the radio button clicked. The `for=""` is the trick there.

Finally, Surround each group of ratings in a `<div class="ratings">` so they can all belong to their own group with a shared style.

```css
.feedback-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.feedback-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}


.ratings {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-background">

  <div class="feedback-content">

    <img src="E:\IIT\Lectures\WEB\coursework1\Images\feedbackimg1.jpg" alt="Givefeedback" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

    <form action="">

      Name:
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name"> E-Mail:
      <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail"> What do you think about us?<br>
      <textarea rows="6" cols="33" name="comment"></textarea>
      <br> How would you rate us ?
      <br>

      <div class="ratings">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="ExcellentRating" value="Excellent">
        <label for="ExcellentRating">Excellent</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ratings">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="VeryGoodRating" value="Very Good">
        <label for="VerGoodRating">Very Good</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ratings">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="AverageRating" value="Average">
        <label for="AverageRating">Average</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ratings">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="PoorRating" value="Poor">
        <label for="PoorRating">Poor</label>
      </div>
      <div class="ratings">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="ExtremelyPoorRating" value="Extremely Poor">
        <label for="ExtremelyPoorRating">Extremely Poor</label>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>

      <a href="#" id="btn1">SUBMIT</a>

    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```